# Usage of "power"

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm writing an essay and don't know how to phrase this.

The line is where I need a word but am clueless about what word to use.

> Power is such a conflicted ______ in the household

In this context, power is as in control or authority.

Any help is useful, thanks!

Edit: Due to suggestions of adding more context, here's an attempt...
The essay is a novel study, the paragraph this is in is talking about the theme of Knowledge is Power. At this part, I'm explaining how two of the characters fight to have more power than the other within the family, and about the social hierarchy in place.

Comment: You also need to describe what the sentence should *mean*. Since you're writing the essay, you must be trying to convey something. Explain what that is, and we can come up with words to express that.

Comment: IMO, " privilege" may fit the sentence.

Comment: "Mathematical function"?

Comment: The question and the answers have attracted the attention of a drive-by downvoter. The guilty person displays no intention to inform or debate and merely represents a deplorable mute and judgemental attitude. One is too often reminded by such behaviour of the Doge’s letter box.

Comment: Power is such a conflicted **dynamic** in the household.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I suggest "dynamic" but none of us knows what you are trying to convey.

MW

> Definition of dynamic (Entry 2 of 2) : a force or factor that controls
> or influences a process of growth, change, interaction, or activity :
> a dynamic force or factor a social/cultural/interpersonal dynamic

Answer (score -1):

Questions are sometimes closed for lack of research but you admit to being clueless about this so you cannot reasonably be expected to have done research on it. I therefore answer with three suggestions:

> Matter = a situation or subject that is being dealt with or considered:
>
> Issue = a subject or problem that people are thinking and talking about:
>
> Topic = a subject that is discussed, written about, or studied:
>
> [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/topic?q=Topic)

From these definitions you may also recognise *subject* as a justifiable possibility for your choice of word.

Answer (score -1):

I would have gone for *force*.

"Power is such a conflicting **force** in the household".

Answer (score -1):

"Power is such a conflicting ***privilege*** in the household."

I chose "privilege" based on the following points.

1. In Oxford English Dictionary, "privilege" means a special right or advantage that only one person or group has.
2. Power in a household, normally means who is in charge or to command the family. Everyone among husband, wife, sons, daughters in the household can be the person who has a privilege to give orders; accordingly they have responsibility to run the family well.

3.Power in a household has two sides that means the person or group who has a privilege is required to give up something to balance the benefits in the household.

4."conflict" means argurements and inequalities which everyone in the household ought to handle and settle. Where there is power, where there are conflicts.